# How can I replicate specific random draws in loops of different size?

Tags: r, random

I am struggling to understand how to replicate results from earlier work. I set a seed before I ran a loop with runs X, where some randomness happens in each iteration of the loop. I am now running a smaller loop with runs Y trying to replicate results in only a couple of iterations of that bigger loop (i.e., Y < X). I can't figure out how to do this. Any help much appreciated. MWE is below.

```
set.seed(23) 
big_loop<-sapply(1:5,function(i) {
  saveRDS(.Random.seed,paste0("run_",i,".RDS"))
  sample(letters,1)
}) 

#I want to replicate the random letter draws on runs 2 and 3 of the big_loop

#I understand why this doesn't work
set.seed(23)
small_loop<-sapply(2:3,function(i) {
  sample(letters,1)
})

#but I'm not sure why this doesn't work.
#how can I make it match runs 2 and 3 of the big loop?
set.seed(23)
small_loop2<-sapply(2:3,function(i) {
  .Random.seed<-readRDS(paste0("run_",i,".RDS"))
  sample(letters,1)
})

#i want this to be false
identical(big_loop[1:2],small_loop) #true
identical(big_loop[1:2],small_loop2) #true

#I want these to be true
identical(big_loop[2:3],small_loop) #false
identical(big_loop[2:3],small_loop2) #false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R uses `.Random.seed` from the **global environment**, so you have to assign it there: assigning it inside the function environment won't work (as you have seen).

```
small_loop2<-sapply(2:3,function(i) {
   assign(".Random.seed",readRDS(paste0("run_",i,".RDS")),
         envir=.GlobalEnv)
  sample(letters,1)
})
small_loop2
## [1] "f" "i"
big_loop
## [1] "o" "f" "i" "s" "v"
```

The other, slightly more convenient solution to this problem is to set the seed sequentially *within* each run:

```
big_loop<-sapply(1:5,function(i) {
  set.seed(22+i)
  sample(letters,1)
}) 
small_loop<-sapply(2:3,function(i) {
  set.seed(22+i)
  sample(letters,1)
})
```

This way you can reproduce results without moving the unwieldy contents of `.Random.seed` around ...

Sequential seeds are recommended [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/01/29/random-number-generator-seed-mistakes/); apparently the SQL `RAND()` is [not reliable when seeded with sequential values](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/RAND()/140883/), but I don't think that's an issue with R's generators ...

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Is there a more elegant way to do what I am trying to do?